# How to change Android Device name on Android 6 & 7 programmatically?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to change `Android` device name instead of `bluetooth` adapter name.

Using this code :

```
BluetoothAdapter myBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
myBTAdapter.setName("new_name");
```

I am able to change the `bluetooth` adapter name which is being treated as Android device name as well on Kitkat and Lollipop.
But on Marshmallow and Nougat device name and `bluetooth` adapter name is different. So how can I change Android device name `progrmmatically`?

Is there any way out to change Android device name `progrmmatically` or we need to change it manually only?

Comment: hi 
please if you finds  any solution share here

Answer (score -1):

Did you use these permissions ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```